# Filtering NSString Objects from an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsstring, nsmutablearray

My app receives the user's input from a text field and generates all the possible words which can be made from the letters.

If the user types in "BOX", the program generates a mutable array which contains such words as: "BO", "BOB", "BOO", "OX".

I just need to filter out the words which contain duplicate letters that are not present in the user's input. So, I need to filter out "BOB" and "BOO."

I guess another solution would be to avoid generating BOB and BOO in the first place, but I haven't figured that out either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate all possible combinations from the letters of the given word (where each
letter is used only once) you can use the following recursive method:

```
- (NSArray *)allWordsFrom:(NSString *)word
{
    NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self addAllWordsFrom:word withPrefix:@"" toMutableArray:a];
    return a;
}

- (void)addAllWordsFrom:(NSString *)letters withPrefix:(NSString *)prefix toMutableArray:(NSMutableArray *)a
{
    [letters enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [letters length])
                    options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                 usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                     // Add one letter to the prefix:
                     NSString *word = [prefix stringByAppendingString:substring];
                     [a addObject:word];
                     // Build combinations with remaining letters:
                     NSString *remainingLetters = [letters stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:substringRange withString:@""];
                     if ([remainingLetters length] > 0) {
                         [self addAllWordsFrom:remainingLetters withPrefix:word toMutableArray:a];
                     }
                 }];
}
```

For the word "BOX" this creates the list

```
B, BO, BOX, BX, BXO, O, OB, OBX, OX, OXB, X, XB, XBO, XO, XOB
```

and you don't have to filter the array afterwards.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help. I would have never figured that out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array with all possible letters is `allCombinations` you can use the
`filteredArrayUsingPredicate` function of NSArray to create a filtered array. Therefor you need to define a precidate which can be done easily using a block:

```
NSPredicate *filterPrecicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock: ^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *bind){
    BOOL filterEntry;
    // do actually filtering a set filterEntry to YES/NO
    return filterEntry
}];
```

After creating the block you can do the filtering:

```
NSArray *filteredCombinations = [allCombinations filteredArrayUsingPredicate: filterPrecicate];
```

Comment: I really need to study blocks some more. I started trying something similar, but I couldn't figure out how to use blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that will filter your array as requested. You can modify it slightly to use predicate filtering if you like.

```
NSCountedSet *letterBinsForWord(NSString *word)
{
    NSCountedSet *bins = [NSCountedSet set];
    for (NSUInteger i=0, n=word.length;  i<n;  i++) {
        NSString *letter = [word substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
        [bins addObject:letter];
    }
    return bins;
}

BOOL letterBinsIncludesBins(NSCountedSet *set0, NSCountedSet *set1)
{
    for (NSString *letter in set1) {
        if ([set0 countForObject:letter] < [set1 countForObject:letter])
            return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSString *userText = @"boox";
        NSArray  *words = @[@"box",@"ox",@"boo",@"booo",@"bo",@"bin"];

        NSCountedSet *letterBins = letterBinsForWord(userText);
        NSMutableArray *filteredWords = [NSMutableArray array];

        for (NSString *word in words) {
            NSCountedSet *bins = letterBinsForWord(word);
            if (letterBinsIncludesBins(letterBins, bins))
                [filteredWords addObject:word];
        }

        NSLog(@"Filtered words: %@",filteredWords);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For the userText "boox" (with two 'o') I get the following output:

```
Filtered words: (
    box,
    ox,
    boo,
    bo
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.